# Why does download captions return Login Required?

Tags: oauth, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I tried show captions in the video via URL but It's tell me login required

**My attempt**

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/BoaAKQZq5TEG3wdKFklJrnQZ3_7OayFqRJtSUDTo9Ck=?tfmt=ttml&tlang=en&key=I_Hid_My_Key

The result is Login Required

**The source**

[Captions: download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to understand is the diffidence between private and public user data.  Public data is just that public anyone can access it.  Youtube Video search for example searches for public youtube videos.

> [Videos captions download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) Downloads a caption track. The caption track is returned in its original format unless the request specifies a value for the tfmt parameter and in its original language unless the request specifies a value for the tlang parameter.

This data is private data.  It can only be accessed by the captions on a video with the permission and [Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) of the owner of the video..  In you are currently using an **api** key denoted by `key=` which is only used for accessing public data.  You will need to be authenticated using one of the below scopes in order to access this information.

> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes (read more about authentication and authorization).
>
> Scope
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner

Comment: Okay thanks @DalmTo I understand that all users can get public data like (search,likes count , dislike count ,views count ,comments etc) , But the question now if I want to get captions from any video I should ask owner video firstly ?

Comment: Yes if you want access to private user data then the owner of that data will need to be authenticated using Oauth2.

Comment: @DalmTo In fact I can't understand Oauth2 well , How I can use Oauth2?

Comment: The documentation contain information on Oauth https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application give it a try and open a new question if you have any issues